# How to use rename_with and substring in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, substring, rename

I have a dataframe called **emp** which has some column names like "X.2008_PLDF", "X.2009_SDF" and "county_name".

I want to rename the columns with numbers in them so that they are just the 4 digit numbers.

This is what I am trying:

```
rename_with(emp, str_sub(names(emp),2,5), starts_with("X"))
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Can't convert a character vector to function

Not really sure what I am meant to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to test without an example but something like this should work

```
rename_with(emp, ~str_sub(.,2,5), starts_with("X"))
```

Comment: Hi, looks like this worked, but i changed the str_sub to substr as iI was getting "can't find function str_sub". 

Quick question:
1. Do you know why str_sub was not found?
2. What does the "~" and "." do in this context? I assume it's some kind of lambda thing? I am new to R so don't know much yet.

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: `str_sub` is a function within `stringr` so you need to load that library. (It's also part of `tidyverse`)

The tilde/dot is a form of non standard evaluation, the tilde says compute this differently, the dot is where to plug in the input
You can probably find a better description than that elsewhere though.